# Java -HTTP URL connection downloaded file with empty

Tags: java, asp.net, authorization, httpurlconnection, filestream

Trying to downloading a file from url (this service is developed in .net soap request) using java (HttpURLConnection class) i'm getting HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK file successfully downloaded with empty content (i.e 0kb)

Code:

```
        String userCredentials = "abc:cde";
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url
                .openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic "+ userCredentials);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "Application/octet-stream");
        connection.setChunkedStreamingMode(4096);
        connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", url.toString());

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            String saveFilePath = saveDir + File.separator + downloadFileName;
            System.out.println(saveFilePath);

            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(saveFilePath);
            int bytesRead ;
            byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
```

Output:

```
HTTPResponse code : 200
File downloaded with empty
```

Note: response header

```
{null=[HTTP/1.1 200 OK], Server=[Microsoft-IIS/8.5], Cache-Control=[private], X-AspNet-Version=[4.0.30319], Content-Length=[0], Date=[Fri, 15 Jun 2018 09:14:07 GMT], X-Powered-By=[ASP.NET]}
```

Answer (score -1):

You're not connecting resources.
Add `connection.connect()` before your `responseCode = httpurlconnection.http_ok`sentence.

Comment: getting same thing

Comment: If you are using a browser, is there anything in the file you downloaded